# Notation for the Subgroup Generated by Two Elements of a Finite Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, abelian-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite Abelian group. Let $a$, $b
\in G$. Prove that the set $\langle a,b\rangle=\{a^ib^j:i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

This is a rather easy problem, but I was hoping for some clarification on the question itself. In the *text*, the author merely defines what $\langle S\rangle$ is for any subset of any group $G$, namely it is the subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ and if $H$ is any subgroup of $G$ containing $S$, then $\langle S\rangle\subseteq H$. So it seems it follows automatically from the definition that $\langle a,b\rangle$ will be a subgroup of $G$ if $a,b\in G$, right?

However, in the text the author does make a distinction that with group elements $a$, $b$ *that commute*, we have $\langle a,b\rangle = \{a^qb^r:q,r\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

So this problem is really asking me to show that specifically $\langle a,b\rangle=\{a^ib^j:i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ as sets, right?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: As I read it, the author is *defining* $<a,b>$ to be that set, in which case it is not  tautological that it is a subgroup.  It isn't a subgroup in the case of a free group, say.  I agree that it's not great notation, given that standard notation would say that $<a,b>$ is the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: @Shaun Gallian's Contemporary Abstract Algebra.

Comment: Thank you, but which edition? (There's at least ten . . . )

Comment: To stress:  Though I might well be wrong, I do not believe the author is, here,  assuming that $<a,b>$ is the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$.  I think the author intended something like "Letting  $S(a,b)$ denote the set $\{a^ib^j\,:\,i,j\in \mathbb Z\}$, show that $S(a,b)$ is a subgroup".  Of course it would quickly follow that $S(a,b)=<a,b>$.  A plausible alternate reading would be "Show that the subgroup generated by $a$ and $b$ is equal to the set of elements of the form  $\{a^ib^j\,:\,i,j\in \mathbb Z\}$".  In the end, you have to prove pretty much the same things either way.

Comment: @Shaun No problem. 8th edition, Chapter $3$. The relevant definition is on page $66$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are entirely correct.

For a subset $S\subseteq G$ of a group $G$ we denote by $\langle S\rangle$ the *subgroup generated by* $S$, which is the smallest subgroup containing $S$. This is equivalent to requiring $\langle S\rangle$ to be a subgroup and having the minimality property that it is contained in any subgroup $H$ containing $S$, i.e. to the conditions you stated.

So yes, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is always a subgroup by definition but its precise nature is unclear without further assumptions. Hence the task here is to show that for any abelian group (or for any two commuting elements as you have rightfully noted) we can describe $\langle a,b\rangle$ set-theoretically as $\{a^ib^j\,|\,i,j\in\mathbb Z\}$.

This business becomes a whole lot clearer once you know about free groups and such.

---

Also note *lulu*'s excellent comment remarking that the issue here might actually be of notational nature.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! At the end of the day it seems the important fact to get at is that we can write any element of this subgroup as $a^ib^j$ for some integers $i$ and $j$, because $G$ is Abelian.

Comment: @upanddownintegrate Exactly! For an arbitrary *non-abelian* group you would also get stuff like $ababab$ which you possibly cannot simplify further. If the above answer your question feel free to accept it (:

Comment: Coming back to this now, it seems to prove that $\langle a,b \rangle = \{a^ib^j:i,j\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ it's clear that $\{a^ib^j:i,j\in \mathbb{Z}\}\subseteq \langle a,b \rangle$ by closure but to prove the other way around I take an arbitrary *word* in $\langle a,b \rangle$ and show by Abelian-ness that it can be written as $a^ib^j$?

Comment: @upanddownintegrate Precisely that!

Answer (score 0):

If $a,b$ are elements of a given group, $\langle a,b\rangle$ is just a shorthand for $\langle \{a,b\}\rangle$. Similarly for any other number of elements.