# Subgroup Generated by Two Elements of a Finite Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a finite Abelian group and let $a, b\in G$. Prove that the set $\langle a, b \rangle = \{ a^ib^j: i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4607429/689775) for clarification about this question yesterday and now have I have a question about its proof. In the spirit of what I don't know, I have decided to interpret this problem as asking us to prove that, as sets, $\langle a, b \rangle = \{ a^ib^j: i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ since we already know $\langle S \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$ for any subset $S\subseteq G$ *by definition*.

My argument seems correct, I'm really just wondering if anyone has a cleaner way to do it.

**Proof**:

Clearly $\{ a^ib^j: i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}\subseteq \langle a,b \rangle$ since $\langle a,b \rangle$ is closed among products of integer powers of its elements. Now if any word $g=s_1^{n_1}s_2^{n_2}\cdot\ldots\cdot s_m^{n_m} \in\langle a,b \rangle$ for $m\in\mathbb{Z}\geq1$ and $s_i\in\{a,b\}$, then let $k$ be the least positive integer (by Well-Ordering if you like) such that $s_k=a.$

- If $k>1$, then $s_{k-1}=b$ so by commutativity and induction $\ldots s_{k-1}^{n_{k-1}}s_k^{n_k}\ldots=\ldots s_k^{n_k}s_{k-1}^{n_{k-1}}\ldots$ ;

  - if $k-1=1$, we're done so then consider the least positive integer $l$ such that $s_l=a$;
  - if $k-1\neq1$, then we repeat the argument above so that $\ldots s_{k-2}^{n_{k-2}}s_k^{n_k}\ldots=\ldots s_k^{n_k}s_{k-2}^{n_{k-2}}\ldots$.

We continue this process until $k-s=1$ for some $s\geq2$ so that $s_k^{n_k}$ is the leftmost term in the word $g$.

- If $k=1$, on the other hand, again we're done so consider the least positive integer $l$ such that $s_l=a$.

Again, $s_{l-1}=b$, so we may show by commutativity and induction that $\ldots s_{l-1}^{n_{l-1}}s_l^{n_l}\ldots=\ldots s_l^{n_l}s_{l-1}^{n_{l-1}}\ldots$ and further may continue this process until $s_{l-t}=a$ for some $t\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ so that $s_l^{n_l}$ is the second leftmost term in the word $g$.

We continue this process until we exhaust the finite number of $a$'s so that $$g=s_k^{n_k}s_l^{n_l}\cdot\ldots\cdot s_{k^*}^{n_{k^*}}s_{l^*}^{n_{l^*}}$$ such that $s_k=s_l=\ldots=a$ and $s_{k^*}=s_{l^*}=\ldots=b$. Thus $g=a^{n_k}a^{n_l}\cdot\ldots\cdot b^{n_{k^*}}b^{n_{l^*}}=a^ib^j$ for some integers $i$ and $j \implies$ $g\in\langle a, b\rangle$.

So we conclude $\langle a,b \rangle\subseteq \{ a^ib^j: i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ or that $\langle a,b \rangle = \{ a^ib^j: i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

For completeness, the Finite Subgroup Test shows $\langle a,b \rangle = \{ a^ib^j: i,j\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ (it's clearly nonempty by construction and a subset of $G$ by closure) since if $a^ib^j,a^nb^m\in\langle a,b \rangle$, then $$(a^ib^j)(a^nb^m)=a^i(b^ja^n)b^m=a^i(a^nb^j)b^m=a^{i+n}b^{j+m}\in\langle a,b \rangle $$
since $i+n$ and $j+m$ are integers. $\blacksquare$

Again, just curious it there's any way to simplify this mess or a different way to do it that avoids this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof of $\{a^ib^j : i,j \in \Bbb Z\} \subseteq \langle a,b \rangle$ is fine.

For the other one, note that $\{a^ib^j : i,j \in \Bbb Z\}$ is a subgroup of $G$ (by using the Finite Subgroup Test as you did) that contains $a$ and $b$ (because $a=a^1b^0$ and $b=a^0b^1$).
Since $\langle a,b \rangle$ is, by definition, the smallest subgroup of $G$ that contains $a$ and $b$; it follows that $\langle a,b \rangle \subseteq \{a^ib^j : i,j \in \Bbb Z\}$.

Comment: Ah gees…this is much simpler.